# SQLite Concatenating Column values

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

There are similar answers for other database types but I haven't found an example for this for SQLite, so I've included the answer that I came up with.

**The Problem**

Given a table like the following

```
╔══════════╦══════╗
║ Item     ║ Tag  ║
╠══════════╬══════╣
║ "Item1"  ║ "A"  ║
║ "Item1"  ║ "B"  ║
║ "Item1"  ║ "C"  ║
║ "Item2"  ║ "A"  ║
║ "Item1"  ║ "D"  ║
║ "Item2"  ║ "F"  ║
║ "Item1"  ║ "E"  ║
╚══════════╩══════╝
```

Create an output of:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║  Item     ║    Tags     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║  "Item1"  ║ "A,B,C,D,E" ║
║  "Item2"  ║ "A,F"       ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 4):

That's what [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) is for:

```
SELECT Item,
       group_concat(Tag) AS Tags
FROM (SELECT Item, Tag
      FROM T
      ORDER BY Item, Tag)
GROUP BY Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (like has been found for other databases) is to use a recursive CTE to join the table back onto itself.

### The Solution

If you just want the solution then here is the final SQL

```
with recursive
complete as
(select Item, Tag, (select count(*) from T b where a.Tag > b.Tag and b.Item = a.Item) as cnt
from T a
),
summary(item, tags, cnt) as
(
    -- Select the initial seed values
    select item, tag, cnt
      from complete
     where cnt = 0
    union all
    -- Concatenate the next rows values onto the previous rows (this is the recursive part)
    select a.item, a.tags || ',' || b.tag, b.cnt
      from summary a
      join complete b on a.item = b.item and a.cnt + 1 = b.cnt
--  limit 200
)
final( ItemID, tags, cnt) as
(
    select ItemID, tags, max(cnt) from summary -- limit the selected values to the final rows concatenated values
    group by ItemID
)
select ItemID, tags from final
;
```

### The explanation

Read on if you want how it works

**First create a test table**

```
--drop table T;
create table T (Item, Tag);

insert into T values('Item1', 'A');
insert into T values('Item1', 'B');
insert into T values('Item1', 'C');
insert into T values('Item2', 'A');
insert into T values('Item1', 'D');
insert into T values('Item2', 'F');
insert into T values('Item1', 'E');

select * from T;
```

That gives you the flat table

```
Item    Tag
"Item1" "A"
"Item1" "B"
"Item1" "C"
"Item2" "A"
"Item1" "D"
"Item2" "F"
"Item1" "E"
```

**Then assign incremental numbers to the items tags**

```
select Item,
    Tag,
    (select count(*) from T b where a.Tag > b.Tag and b.Item = a.Item) as cnt
from T a order by 1,3;  -- note we don't need order later on
```

Which will give a result set of

```
Item    Tag cnt
"Item1" "A" "0"
"Item1" "B" "1"
"Item1" "C" "2"
"Item1" "D" "3"
"Item1" "E" "4"
"Item2" "A" "0"
"Item2" "F" "1"
```

**Then the recursive CTE**

We start with

```
with recursive
```

to say we are doing a CTE

Then assign a table with all the data required - here called complete

```
complete as
(select Item, Tag, (select count(*) from T b where a.Tag > b.Tag and b.Item = a.Item) as cnt
from T a
),
```

Then define the table and columns *must have a place holder for the row number we created before* - here the table is called summary and the rownumber is cnt. tags was used to make it more obvious what is happening

```
summary(item, tags, cnt) as
(
```

Then select the initial seeding values. In this case that is the first row for each of the items.

```
    -- Select the initial seed values
    select item, tag, cnt
      from complete
     where cnt = 0
```

Then we **union all** back to the current table, *Note you can use **union** however it is recommended to use **all** since it doesn't check for duplicates and is therefore quicker*

```
    union all
    -- Concatenate the next rows values onto the previous rows (this is the recursive part)
    select a.item, a.tags || ',' || b.tag, b.cnt
      from summary a
      join complete b on a.item = b.item and a.cnt + 1 = b.cnt
--  limit 200
),
```

**Note that in summary's definition it actually joins back to summary. That is why it's a recursive CTE - and why caution must be used when creating them**

Then cut out the extra rows which we iterated through to get to the final rows concatenated value by only selecting the max row number for each item

```
final( Item, tags, cnt) as
(
    select Item, tags, max(cnt) from summary -- limit the selected values to the final rows concatenated values
    group by Item
)
```

Then select the values from that final cut table

```
select Item, tags from final
;
```

That gives the required summarised data

```
Item    Tags
"Item1" "A,B,C,D,E"
"Item2" "A,F"
```

Note I originally didn't have the final table in there but just had the code

```
select item, tags, max(cnt)  from summary
group by item
having max(cnt) -- limit the selected values to the final rows concatenated values
```

That works for the specific example I gave but not the slightly different stuff I was actually working with, which is why I've added the final table as well.

*Note*

*- The keyword **recursive** is the standard but not required*

*- It's generally a good idea to use the LIMIT functionality when developing a recursive CTE so that if you stuff it up you don't crash - it is currently commented out in the code above.*

*See [SQLite WITH explanation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) for more information about how to do recursive CTE's with SQLite*